# Getting the same instance of an integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I have two view controllers, one by the name of PageMainViewController and the other by the name of PlayerSelectViewController.  An integer named `players` is declared in the .h file of PageMainViewController which will be used to represent how many people are playing.  The integer is set in the .m file of PlayerSelectViewController depending on which button was hit.

PageMainViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PageMainViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)chooseButton:(id)sender;

@property int players;

@end
```

PageMainViewController.m:

```
#import "PageMainViewController.h"

@interface PageMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageMainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)chooseButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Final = %i", _players);

    if (_players == 1) {

    OnePlayerViewController *onePlayerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OnePlayerViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:onePlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (_players == 2) {

    TwoPlayersViewController *twoPlayersViewsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwoPlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:twoPlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (_players == 3) {

    ThreePlayersViewController *threePlayersViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThreePlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:theePlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (_players == 4) {

    FourPlayersViewController *fourPlayersViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourPlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:fourPlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

PlayerSelectViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageMainViewController.h"

@interface PlayerSelectViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)twoPlayers:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)threePlayers:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)fourPlayers:(id)sender;

@end
```

PlayerSelectViewController.m:

```
#import "PlayerSelectViewController.h"

@implementation PlayerSelectViewController

- (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender {

    PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController = [[PageMainViewController alloc] init];
    pageMainViewController.players = 1;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

- (IBAction)twoPlayers:(id)sender {

    PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController = [[PageMainViewController alloc] init];
    pageMainViewController.players = 2;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

- (IBAction)threePlayers:(id)sender {

    PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController = [[PageMainViewController alloc] init];
    pageMainViewController.players = 3;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

 }

- (IBAction)fourPlayers:(id)sender {

    PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController = [[PageMainViewController alloc] init];
    pageMainViewController.players = 4;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

 @end
```

NSLog:

```
1
Final = 0
```

**The integer reset from one to 0, how do I fix it?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It wasn't reset, it's a different instance.

Comment: What's with the down votes.  This is a perfectly good question. I bet some other people might have the same problem.

Comment: Daily? What.. @hot licks

Comment: The question occurs daily.  At least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you select onePlayer/two etc. you are allocating a new instance of PageMainViewController, so it is no longer referencing your initial instance of PageMainViewController.

If PageMainViewController is presenting PlayerSelectViewController, you can refernce the original viewController by changing each IBAction like so:

```
 - (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender {

    PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController = (PageMainViewController*)[self presentingViewController];
    pageMainViewController.players = 1;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}
```

EDIT: With the new pic you attached the PlayerSelectViewController is presenting the PageMainViewController.  You can do it this way:

First, move the players ivar to PlayerSlectViewController like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayerSelectViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)twoPlayers:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)threePlayers:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)fourPlayers:(id)sender;

@property int players;

@end
```

Remove the one you had in the PageMainViewController .h file

Next update the IBActions for onePlayer, twoPlayer, etc like so:

```
- (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender {

    _players = 1;
    NSLog(@"%i", _players);
}
```

Then import PlayerSelectViewController in PageMainViewController.m

```
#import "PlayerSelectViewController.h"
```

Finally, update IBAction chooseButton like so:

```
- (IBAction)chooseButton:(id)sender {
    PlayerSelectViewController* presentingVC = (PlayerSelectViewController*)[self presentingViewController];


    NSLog(@"Final = %i", presentingVC.players);

    if (presentingVC.players == 1) {

    OnePlayerViewController *onePlayerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OnePlayerViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:onePlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (presentingVC.players == 2) {

    TwoPlayersViewController *twoPlayersViewsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwoPlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:twoPlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (presentingVC.players == 3) {

    ThreePlayersViewController *threePlayersViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThreePlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:theePlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    if (presentingVC.players == 4) {

    FourPlayersViewController *fourPlayersViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FourPlayersViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:fourPlayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

Comment: The app crashes using this.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a navigation controller.  Can you show me the code where PageMainViewController presents PlayerSelectViewController?

Comment: I'm not using a navigation controller

Comment: The code for presenting PlayerSelectViewController?

Comment: Look at the the picture I included, it is not done programatically

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are instantiating PageMainViewController in the button action method. And when you present PageMainViewController you use another instance of this class.

Try to declare pageMainViewController as a property of PlayerSelectViewController class, call the init method on PlayerSelectViewController's viewDidLoad and keep setting the integer on button's action method.

Something like that:

```
#import "PlayerSelectViewController.h"

@interface PlayerSelectViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) PageMainViewController *pageMainViewController;

@end

@implementation PlayerSelectViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.pageMainViewController = [[PageMainViewController alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)onePlayer:(id)sender {

    self.pageMainViewController.players = 1;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

- (IBAction)twoPlayers:(id)sender {

    self.pageMainViewController.players = 2;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

- (IBAction)threePlayers:(id)sender {

    self.pageMainViewController.players = 3;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

- (IBAction)fourPlayers:(id)sender {

    self.pageMainViewController.players = 4;
    NSLog(@"%i", pageMainViewController.players);

}

@end
```

Comment: I got the same result "Final = 0" and do you mean self.pageMainViewController.players?

Comment: Yes, self.pageMainViewController.players

Comment: I think the problem is on the instance of PageMainViewController, you are setting the property player of one instance and presenting another one. Insert a `NSLog(@"%@", self.pageMainViewController)` in one of buttons actions and `NSLog(@"%@", self)` in PageMainViewController's `viewDidLoad`. It will print something like <PageMainViewController: 0xde42c10> and if this code is different, the problem is exactly different instances.